# Convert list of chars into a data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe

suppose I have the following list:

```
a=list()
a[1]<-c("1")
a[2]<-c("3")
a[[1]][2]<-c("a")
a[[2]][2]<-c("b")

List of 2
 $ : chr [1:2] "1" "a"
 $ : chr [1:2] "3" "b"

[[1]]
[1] "1" "a"

[[2]]
[1] "3" "b"
```

How can I convert that list into a data frame like this?
This is how the info would looks like:

```
table<-data.frame(col1=c("1a","3b")) 

 col1  
  1a
  3b

'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ col1: Factor w/ 2 levels "1a","3b": 1 2
```

Comment: `data.frame(col1 = sapply(a, paste0, collapse = ""))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use , `do.call` as well however, I do feel the answer in the comment is better than this:

```
df <- setNames(data.frame(do.call("paste0",data.frame(do.call("rbind",a)))),"col1")
```

You can always read about `do.call` from documentation:

> do.call constructs and executes a function call from a name or a
>   function and a list of arguments to be passed to it.

**Output:**

```
> df
  col1
1   1a
2   3b

> str(df)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ col1: Factor w/ 2 levels "1a","3b": 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and let me know in case of any queries.

```
a=list()
a[1]<-c("1")
a[2]<-c("3")
a[[1]][2]<-c("a")
a[[2]][2]<-c("b")

b <- t(data.frame(a))
data.frame(col1=paste0(b[,1],b[,2]))
```